# Roslyn not finding all references

Tags: c#, roslyn

I'm using Roslyn to rewrite some methods used throughout a solution.

I was able to find and fix many instances. However, it's not finding all references. Many more show up in Visual Studio with CodeLens or using "Find All References." The solution compiles with no errors.

The references it's not finding seem to be only overloaded methods called from web applications in the solution. But it finds references to non-overloaded methods in these web applications.

I'm finding the symbols for the necessary methods and looping through them, searching for references like this:

```
MSBuildWorkspace workspace = MSBuildWorkspace.Create();
Solution solution = await workspace.OpenSolutionAsync(@"..\Solutions\Main.sln");

var symbols = await FindSymbols(solution);

foreach (var symbol in symbols)
{
    var callers = await SymbolFinder.FindCallersAsync(symbol, solution);
    // Modify code
}

workspace.TryApplyChanges(solution);
```

I've also tried `SymbolFinder.FindReferencesAsync()` and it also does not find the remaining references.

I can't figure out what to do to allow Roslyn to find these additional references that are found in Visual Studio.

Comment: You need to show your code how you are loading the solution.

Comment: Check for semantic errors.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I provided a more complete example and added some more information. I don't think it has to do with how the solution is loaded because it *is* finding references in the same projects that it's missing some.

Comment: @SLaks You mean in the code where the references are that it's not finding? The solution compiles and the references can be found in Visual Studio.

Comment: I mean in your `Workspace`.  You might be loading something differently from VS.

Comment: @SLaks I'm loading the same solution in the workspace as in Visual Studio. I also added some more information. It is finding some references in the same projects that it is missing references in. It seems like it may only be having trouble finding overloaded methods called from web applications for some reason.

Comment: Check for compilation errors in your `Solution`.

Comment: @SLaks the solution compiles with no errors.